# Buddypress Registartion template

Tags: buddypress, user-registration

How do I create a registration template in Buddypress? I can't seem to find any way to integrate the registration form in a template page. I tried adding this code to my template page, it displays nothing but a blank form:

http://pastebin.com/QsL65A53

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

---

Now I have this in my front-page.php file:
http://pastebin.com/ZeK43zkv

It shows all the fields but doesn't work. When I click the signup button it returns the same page and does not register the user. Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this snippit below the get_header section:

```
<?php
global $bp;

if(empty($bp->signup->step))

$bp->signup->step='request-details';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the [BP Template Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bp-template-pack/) plug-in and allow it to migrate BuddyPress's theme files to your current theme. After this is done, you will find a new folder called "registration" in your theme's root directory. Inside is a file called "register.php" which contains the registration form.

Comment: I copied the code from the buddypress default template's registration.php file actually. look at the pastebin link. pasted it in my custom template page. doesn't show a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regular WordPress page template (BP does not support this at the moment). Put it in a template file located at `registration/register.php` in your theme.